# FormMail not sending image

Tags: php, formmail

I'm using the latest version of Matts formmail but for some reason I'm not able to configure image upload. Is the script capable of image upload? or is this an html problem in my form?

It is uploading this form. Wiling to make a small donation to whoever helps.

```
    <form id="buy-online" class="automatic-pricing c7" action="FormMail/formmail.pl"      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="c1" id="buy-online-header">Get a QuickQuote</div>
<br />
<div class="row c2"><label id="label-product" for="ddl-product"><span>Product:</span>           </label> <select id="product-data" name="ddl_product">
<option value="">Select a product...</option>
<option value="Luxury">Luxury Lawn</option>
<option value="Lush">Lush Lawn</option>
<option value="Natural">Natural Lawn</option>
<option value="RG Basic">RG Basic</option>
<option value="------">-------</option>
<option value="Multiple">Multiple, please state below</option>
</select></div>
<div class="row c2">
<label><br>
Width: <input type="text" name="Width" id="Width" /></label></div>
<div class="row c2">
<label><br>
Length: <input type="text" name="Length" id="Length" /></label></div>
<div>
<br>
Ground Conditions
<textarea style="width:450px" name="Ground Conditions"></textarea>

</div>
<div>
<br>
<div>Comments and Requests
  <textarea style="width:450px" name="Ground Conditions3"></textarea>
</div>
</div><br />
  <div class="c3">
  Area Photos</div>
<div class="c4" id="file1"><input name="Image 1" type="file" /></div>
<div class="c5" id="file1"><input name="Image 1" type="file" /></div>
<div class="c4" id="file1"><input name="Image 1" type="file" /></div>
<div class="c4" id="file1"><input name="Image 1" type="file" /></div>
<div class="c5" id="file1"><input name="Image 1" type="file" /></div>
<div class="c3"><br />
Your Garden Plan<br />
<div class="c6" id="file1"><input name="Image 1" type="file" /></div>
<br /></div>
<div>
Phone Number<br>
<label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
</label>
<textfield style="width:450px" name="phonenumber"></textfield>
<br>
<br>
</div>
<div>
Post Code<br>
<label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
</label>
<textfield style="width:450px" name="phonenumber"></textfield>
<br>
<br>
</div>
<div class="row-button"><button id="button-buy-now" name="btn_buy_now" type="submit">        <span>Get a Quote</span></button></div>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect"    value="http://www.sgsgrass.co.uk/submitconfirmation.php" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: FAQ for that script: http://www.scriptarchive.com/faq/formmail.html

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything?

Comment: http://archives.hwg.org/hwg-techniques/3F8479E5.31A0@erols.com